# Temporary view works, /mydb/_design/mydesigndoc/_view/myview doesn't. Why?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, kanso

Hi!

New to web developing in general, couchdb in specific.

Right now I try to understand how to call views. I have fairly simple documents generated and submitted to the my database through an app based on [Simplest possible form found on Kan.so](http://kan.so/docs/Simplest_possible_form) and I try out different views in Futon. All well. Then I try to create a view in the design-document and call from within the code. To no avail.

Even such a simple view as the following delivers correct in a temporary view:

```
function(doc) {
if (doc.type == 'person') {
    emit(doc._id, doc);
   }
};
```

But put into the `lib/views.js`-file like this (only `exports.map_type =` added):

```
exports.map_type = function(doc) {
if (doc.type == 'person') {
    emit(doc._id, doc);
   }
};
```

wont work when called even from the address-field in the browser like this:

```
http://localhost:5984/simplestpossibleform/_design/my_form/_view/map_type
```

and results as follows:

```
{"error":"unknown_error","reason":"function_clause"}
```

So, something is wrong in the function clause. Well, I cannot see it. The code is copy-pasted from Futons temporary view. And when I try the view from the dropdown it faults while doing a cut and paste from the design doc to the temporary view in Futon works perfect. Maybe there is something else wrong, just can't figure it out.

Can anyone, please, help me?

(Running on couchdb 1.2, Kanso 0.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

I have answered my own question again. And it was pretty elementary, again.

So, *if* I want couchdb to `view`something for me *I* have to tell it whether it is a matter of `map` or `reduce`. I didn't. Here goes the simple (and embarassing) solution:

```
exports.map_type = {
map: function(doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'person') {
        emit(doc._id, doc);
    }
  }
};
```

Anyways, I have learned from my misstake. I hope someone else can make use of my ramblings too..

Comment: thank you for answering your own question once you found the answer!